# SQL monthbase, show monthbase only once per day, left join

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql, date-arithmetic

I have added "Monthbase" to my Time table. Now I want to add it to the Fact table.
Using a left join:

```
 SELECT t1.[Posting_Date]
       ,t1.[Quantity]
       ,t1.[EmployeeID] --added afterwards
       ,t2.[Monthbase]
   FROM [Fact table] t1 LEFT JOIN [Time table] t2
     ON t1.[Posting_Date] = t2.[Posting_Date]
```

[image: Monthbase]

But I only want to see the value (8) one time per day, when applicable.
The Time table has already been created with all requirements regarding holidays etc.

Comment: Not clear for me. What is meaning of trailing zeros?

Comment: The trailing zeros show where the value 8 should be 0, for monthbase

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this:

```
;WITH CTE AS
(
  SELECT [EmployeeID],
        [Posting_Date]
       ,[Quantity]
       ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [EmployeeID], [Posting_Date] ORDER BY [Quantity]) RN
   FROM [Fact table]
)
SELECT t1.[Posting_Date]
       ,t1.[EmployeeID]
       ,t1.[Quantity]
       ,CASE WHEN t1.RN = 1 THEN t2.[Monthbase] ELSE 0 END [Monthbase]
   FROM CTE t1
     LEFT JOIN [Time table] t2
       ON t1.[Posting_Date] = t2.[Posting_Date]
```

Comment: Nice this works, the ROWNUMBER() is missing a _ (ROW_NUMBER) for it to run in my case.
Thank you Hamlet!

Comment: How would you do this if we added  [EmployeeID]???
So that the number would be in the first row per employee